# Javascript: Checking if the class changes with required field entry not input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capture if a user does not fill in a form correctly and the application presents the user with error message(s).  The application changes the class property on all required fields.

when I attach the click event on the submit, I cannot get the error, as the page refreshes after the user clicks the submit.  So I put my code in a settimeout and tested it under several timeouts, 500, 1000, 3000 ms.  I have not had success, do this:

My HTML:

```html
<div class="errorMsg"><strong>Error:</strong> You must enter a value</div>
```

My Javascript:

```js
 setTimeout(
    function() {
        var errors = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="error"]');

        if (errors.length == 0) {
            alert('no errors');
        }

        if (errors.length > 0) {
            alert('errors');
        }
    }, 3000
);
```

Comment: Can we use `button` type instead of `submit`? I think that should resolve the issue. Or else you have to manually prevent the refresh after clicking on `submit` button using `preventDefault`.

Comment: @MilindAgrawal, i just want to point out that the default value for 'type' attribute for button is "submit"(except IE), so there is no differences between <button> and <input type="submit"> ... so may be, what u mean is <button type="button">, but if u use <button type="button">, u need to call submit function explicitly.

Comment: Yup that's correct. You can either call it explicitly or prevent the default behaviour of submit.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, it's better in this case to avoid to default submit behavior and add a listener that will validate the input on click and if all correct will call the respective function.
If not, change the classes appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can put the function to check whether the error exists or not inside the click event handler, and if the error exists, we can cancel the click event using e.preventDefault();

something like this

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="input-email" class="input-email" name="email">
    <button type="submit" onClick="SubmitClick()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

on Javascript, u can use function like this

```
 function SubmitClick(event) {
     var input = document.getElementById("input-email").value;

     if (input == "") 
     {
         alert('error !!!. name can not be empty');
         event.preventDefault();
     }
 }
```